# Will there be future support for the pepper version of flashplugin for Firefox?

Tags: firefox, flash

I have both Firefox and Chromium installed, the latter with the pepperflashplugin enabled.

Some sites no longer support the 11.2 version of Flash which is all I can get for Firefox. Is there at least talk of supporting pepper support for Firefox? I hate to think I won't be able to use Firefox any more.

Answer (score 2):

It is very unlikely that firefox will support the "pepper API" in the near future. There is a bugreport asking for the support [here](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=729481), it was opened on 2012-02-22 and was closed on the same they as WONTFIX.

Also there was a newer discussion between Mozilla developers [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mozilla.dev.platform/BwWeQwLACiM), with basically the same result: They are not going to support the "pepper API" in the near future (or at all).

It is also important to note that the pepper version of flash is made by Google, not Adobe. One quote from the previous link:

> Even if Firefox supported the Pepper API, we would still need a Pepper
>   version of Flash. And Adobe doesn't have one; Google does.

There are also some very interesting talks and facts about the "pepper API" in those two linked discussions, if you read them through you will get the idea why it is very unlikely that "pepper flash" will arrive to firefox.

What you can do to get "better" flash support for Firefox is to install `pipelight`, which is a browser plugin which utilizes WINE to allow windows only plugins to run in a linux browser. So you can run the windows version of Silverlight, Flash, etc. from the linux version of Firefox. You can read more about it [here](http://fds-team.de/cms/articles/2013-08/pipelight-using-silverlight-in-linux-browsers.html). To install it do:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:pipelight/stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install pipelight-multi
```

Then to activate the pipelight flash plugin in firefox (and also deactivate the linux flash plugin):

```
sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/lib/mozilla/plugins/flashplugin-alternative.so" "mozilla-flashplugin" /usr/lib/pipelight/libpipelight-flash.so 1
sudo update-alternatives --set mozilla-flashplugin /usr/lib/pipelight/libpipelight-flash.so
```

(If you would like to restore the original linux flash plugin later you will have to run

```
sudo update-alternatives --remove mozilla-flashplugin /usr/lib/pipelight/libpipelight-flash.so
```

)

The pipelight installation instructions were taken directly from the developers' website, from [here](http://fds-team.de/cms/pipelight-installation.html).

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04 will bring its own official pepperflashplugin-nonfree package which downloads 'google-chrome-stable_34.0.1847.116-1_amd64.deb' and extracts the flash plugin part of it. So there _is_ something we can call an 'official' pepper plugin. This works with chromium and would be nice to have support for it also in firefox - especially after May 2014 when adobe discontinued support for the original plugin

Answer (score 1):

Mozilla is developing its own flash support on Firefox,it's called Shumway.

Comment: Shumway is available as an extension from mozilla.github.io/shumway/‎ for the adventurous.

Answer (score 0):

pepper-flash is specific to Chrome and to my knowledge it will never be available in any other browsers. We survived before flash came to linux, and we'll survive it's withdrawal.